# Is this access to temporary safe according to the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lifetime, temporary-objects

I recently found the following code pattern in a C++ code base, and I am now wondering if it is safe according to the C++ standard. (The real code passed the `const char*` pointer through several function layers, but I condensed it down to its essential form.)

```
#include <string>

class NetworkSocket
{
public:
    void SetPort(const char* port)
    {
        m_port = port;
    }

private:
    std::string m_port;
};

int main()
{
    const int     port   = 42;
    NetworkSocket socket = {};

    socket.SetPort(std::to_string(port).c_str());
}
```

Specifically, I want to know if the call to `SetPort()` is safe, or if we are invoking undefined behavior, or accessing (potentially) deleted memory.

I tried to figure it out myself using cppreference, but got stuck in the definitions. I got as far as:

1. `std::to_string()` returns a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue), thus creating a temporary object.
2. The call to `c_str()` extends the temporary's lifetime. ([At least since C++17, before I am not sure.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime))
3. From here on I am not sure. It seems that the lifetime of the temporary ends here, making the access to the `const char*` pointer undefined behavior. However, when I tried running the code through clang`s undefined behavior sanitizer no problems were found... https://godbolt.org/z/EfcvePoWe

*Please quote the relevant standard rules, and explain the differences between the standard versions (if there are any).*

Comment: It's safe. You don't keep it, you copy it. There's a bunch of such answered questions.

Comment: `c_str()` doesn't extend the life, the temporary string is alive until `;`

Comment: If instead it were `private: const char* m_port` with rest of your code unchanged, it would be unsafe.

Comment: @273K I know that having the copy is safe, but I want to know if and why the data I am trying to copy is safe to access.

Comment: Your code is safe. I'm sure there is a dup out there addressing why but I'm on mobile now.

Comment: `std::to_string(port).c_str()` lives until `socket.SetPort(std::to_string(port).c_str());` ends, so you are safe

Comment: @273K Why is the temporary still alive until `;`? The `c_str()` call is already finished and thus the compiler should be free to delete the `std::to_string()` temporary...

Comment: No, a temporary lives until the end of the full expression containing it, with a few exceptions. In this case the full expression is `socket.SetPort(std::to_string(port).c_str())`

Comment: @WeijunZhou Hmm... I found full expressions mentioned in cppreference, but their explanation was too complicated for me to understand. From what I gathered, `std::to_string(port).c_str()` is one full expression stuck into another full expression, but that might be a misunderstanding on my part...

Comment: If an expression `A` is part of another expression `B` under the rules you find on cppreference, then by definition `A` cannot be *the* *full* expression. There is no such thing as "full expression contained in another full expression". I'm not a native English speaker, but note it states *the* full expression, not *a* full expression.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Ah! That makes it rather simple. I am also not a native speaker, so thank you for pointing me to the right sentence in the wall of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is well-defined.

> [12.2 Temporary objects  [class.temporary]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.temporary#3)
>
> ...
> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-
> expression ([intro.execution]) that (lexically) contains the point where
> they were created.

> [1.9 Program execution  [intro.execution]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.execution#10)
>
> ...
> A full-expression is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression.

Here:

```
socket.SetPort(std::to_string(port).c_str());
```

The temporary object is the `std::string` object that's the return value from `std::to_string`. The full-expression is, unremarkably, this entire expression. So the temporary object -- the one that owns its `c_str()` -- gets destroyed after the call to `SetPort()` returns. The End.

(there are two exceptions to this rule, they do not apply here).